# An inequality involving 2-norms of vectors

Tags: inequality, vectors, normed-spaces

I was reading a paper and came across an inequality in a derivation that I am having trouble showing to be true.

Let $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \  y \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

$$ ||x|| \ ||y|| \stackrel{?}{\leq} 0.5 \left( x^{\text{T}}x + y^{\text{T}}y \right) $$

where $|| x || $ denotes the 2-norm of the vector $x$.

Does this inequality hold? If so, how can it be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^Tx = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 = ||x||^2$$

So your inequality can be stated as:

$$||x||\ ||y|| \le^? 0.5(||x||^2 + ||y||^2)$$

The left-hand side is the geometric mean of $||x||^2$ and $||y||^2$.  The right-hand side is the arithmetic mean of the same numbers.  [So the AM-GM inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a.m.-g.m.-inequality) applies, and we indeed have $||x||\ ||y|| \le 0.5(||x||^2 + ||y||^2)$.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your response. Your explanation is very clear and easy to understand.